# C++, making OpenCV 3.0.0 available with HDR API

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, hdr

I am using `OpenCV 2.4.6` on my Mac using XCode IDE. I am trying to create HDR images and I found this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/photo/hdr_imaging/hdr_imaging.html#hdrimaging).

When I build it, it doesn't recognize, for example, `CalibrateDebevec` identifier. The problem is that in the header files of `photo.hpp`, it is not declared.  In the tutorial is written that the base is OpenCV 3.0.0.

How can I make `OpenCV 3.0.0` available?

I already tried to download these files from `http://193.87.95.148/openwrt/mx23/trunk/dl/opencvtrunk-2.5.0/` and pasted the headers files into my include folder, but when I solve one problem, 10 more problems appear.

Answer (score 2):

You can build OpenCV 3.0.0 from the current DevZone root master repository at http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository. Clone that repository and use cmake + options, make, and make install, just as you would when building any version of OpenCV. Good luck!